# an object or some objects

Tags: grammaticality

Fact:
Each object has a speed parameter

Which of the following grammatical and sounds better?

> We use the symbol c[t1] henceforth, where c is a speed function and
>    t1 is a speed parameter for **an object** obj1.
>
> We use the symbol c[t1] henceforth, where c is a speed function and
>   t1 is a speed parameter for **some objects** obj1.
>
> We use the symbol c[t1] henceforth, where c is a speed function and
>   t1 is a speed parameter for **any object** obj1.
>
> We use the symbol c[t1] henceforth, where c is a speed function and
>   t1 is a speed parameter. (just omit it)

what I want to say is that obj1 is just any object, not a particular one.

Answer (score 2):

I like this the best:

> We use the symbol c[t1] henceforth, where c is a speed function and t1 is a speed parameter for any object obj1.

However I think it sounds better as this:

> We use the symbol c[t1] henceforth, where c is a speed function and t1 is a speed parameter for any given object.

Comment: "for any given object", this sounds very cool :)

Comment: lonehorse, so there is no need to indicate 'obj1' because from the context one argues that 't1' is related with?

Comment: It's hard to tell, because we don't have the context for william007's sentence. In his original statement, he said "what I want to say is that obj1 is just any object, not a particular one," so I just went off of that.

Comment: I think I would use "a given object" here, assuming that one instance of t1 is a parameter for one instance of an object.  It isn't "any" object in this case, it's the object to which the parameter t1 is related.

Answer (score 2):

The index `1` appears to imply that there may be multiple objects, each with its own speed parameter:

> `obj1` has speed parameter `t1`
>   `obj2` has speed parameter `t2`, and so forth.

If this is the case, when you say that "obj1 is just any object, not a particular one" you do not mean that `t1` may be associated with **any** object; you mean, rather, that any object may be represented by `obj1`, but whatever specific object is represented has a specific associated `t1`.

But the very representation of an object in the abstract form `obj1` will ordinarily lead your readers to assume that `obj1` is a variable, capable of representing "any" object. "Any", in that limited application, will be understood.

Consequently, I would suggest:

> t1 is **the** speed parameter associated with **an** object obj1.

And you might consider replacing `1` with `n`, the conventional representation of an integer variable:

> We use the symbol c[t<sub>*n*</sub>] henceforth, where c is a speed function and t<sub>*n*</sub> is the speed parameter associated with an object obj<sub>*n*</sub>.